# Is it possible to schedule my laptop to mute and unmute based on calendar events?

Tags: applications, audio, mac-appstore, automator, sound-volume

I would like my mac (OSX 10.9) to automatically mute during meetings.  I have a fully abstracted calendar, with several sub calendars.

Any apps?
Any Automator tricks?

Answer (score 2):

### Step 1: Automator tasks

Create an Automator task, and save it (take note of the task file location). You probably want a couple Automator tasks in this case (one to mute and one to unmute).

Here's a very basic mute script:

```
set volume output volume 0
```

And unmute:

```
set volume output volume 100
```

After you've created both Automator task files,

### Step 2: Scheduling with Calendar.app

Go to Calendar, add an event when you want to mute. In the choices for the "alert", choose *custom* and then *Open File*. Choose the appropriate task file you created.

Do the same for the unmute event and task.

Answer (score 2):

Open Automator app

Click on Calender and find and Drag the Find Calender Events

Select the Event has attendees! (obviously :) !

On left select the Utilities and find drag the set computer volume to the right.

Run a test in Automator to verify the Mute is activated, and save the file.

[image]